# App transfer to SD Card, error, on Samsung 0n5 device

Tags: android

Android5.1.1:Samsung Galaxy On5: "Unable to move app.....ok" pop up message appears if following steps are performed,
* Go to the App manager, open the app info
* Tap on Move to SD storage(wherever allowed)
* Hit the the back button to go to the previous page
* Come back to the same app info page and tap on the move to SD Storage.

facebook app crashed and got partially deleted, however mybsnl app remained intact and post restart allowed to move the app.

Don't know where to post the bug, hence posting it here.

Answer (score 0):

The App developer has to enable the ability to move an app to your SD card. the older version of Facebook didn't support that . from v37 this feature added to Facebook app. check your app version and if it is below v37 update that .
http://www.androidauthority.com/facebook-v37-lets-you-move-app-to-sd-card-sort-of-619372/